# Sending File Data To Multiple Clients?

Tags: java, networking, asynchronous, nio, channel

I'm trying to figure out the best way to go about writing data transfer code for a client/server system that handles multiple clients at once.

I'm already keeping a List of clients who connect (I'm using NIO non-blocking framework btw).

Isn't it costly on performance to iterate through every client with each read/write pass and write the buffer data to each channel?  Is there a better/more efficient way of doing it?

I've been thinking about dividing up the buffer size based on the number of clients.  Is that a viable solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using selectors (as you seem to be doing) really pays when you're handling a really large number of clients (and why optimize for the case in which you *don't* have a large number of clients ;)

The bottleneck in such system is rarely the CPU which does the iteration, but the I/O anyway, so I wouldn't worry if I where you.

Comment: And are you saying that I should or shouldn't be using a Selector?